# FileMaker script sequence python script

Tags: python, sequence, filemaker

I have wrote a Python script, which basically moves the file created to FTP and a couple of other bits, the script works perfectly when testing, but as soon as I have it run after my FileMaker script using a script sequence I get - "script is missing or is invalid"

I have tried the exact same set up but using a .bat and it seems to work fine so I dont think its a permission/security issue. I am using FileMaker Server 15. Is it just not possible or is there any advice anyone can give me?

Comment: Anyone? Literally feel like ive tried everything

Comment: If it is a Server scheduled script it has to be a system script, .bat will work. Server will not run python script natively. Also, script has to be placed in :\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\Data\Scripts\. Also, Server will use its own user, not the one you are logged in with

Comment: Script is in the scripts folder and I have specified the Administrator account as the user account to run the python script in. I guess as a work around I could write a .bat that will call the python script via cmd?

Comment: FileMaker Server will not run python directly so run it through the .bat. You can also use VBScript, but these are the options you have. On a mac you can run shel scripts.

Comment: Managed to get it working using .bat, not ideal but it does what I need. Thankyou for the advice Nicolai.